# How can I set a transparent image to my form's background in c#?

Tags: c#

I made a transparent background image in photoshop but when I use it as my form's background image,it doesn't use form's back color(blue),so that I cannot use this code to make a transparent form.

```
this.BackColor = Color.blue;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.blue;
```

If I use white color instead,my other tools fore color face problem.I'm trying to make windows form app.I don't know if there are easier & better alternatives to make a transparent form.

What should I do?

Comment: WinForms?  WPF?  Metro?  Silverlight?

Comment: What format is the image (PNG)?

Comment: You want to make the form transparent so you see f.ex. the desktop behind it? That would require a little more than just the transparent image. The only thing that will happen is you  see the background in the form itself through the alpha-channel of the image.

Comment: PNG and GIF support transparency, JPG doesn't.

Comment: Thank you Chris O.I understood my fault!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing a post from here and my own experience with having trouble on form transparency with types of images I expect it's because it's the fact it's JPG and not PNG or some other transparent friendly image format. I had the same problem and when I changed to PNG format it worked for me.

Reading results from a couple of random google searches it seems JPEG doesn't support transparency do to file format limitations.

[Why am I getting a black background around my images when resizing even when Bitmap is set to Graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227113/why-am-i-getting-a-black-background-around-my-images-when-resizing-even-when-bit)